# Why does the variadic template argument deduction fail for this function pointer?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates, template-argument-deduction

In the following minimal example, `S::foo` works, but `S::bar` fails.

The only difference is the order of the parameter packs `Ts` and `Us`.

`struct FPtr` and `S::lol` are the best workaround I've found, but it's rather uncomfortable to use in practice.

Why does the argument deduction for `bar` fail (especially since I've explicitly specified the types, so no deduction should happen at all)? Is this a compiler bug (occurs with `clang++ 3.5` and `g++ 4.9`), or is this in the standard, for some reason?

```
template<typename ... Ts>
struct FPtr {
    FPtr(void (*val)(Ts ...)) : val{val} {}

    void (*val)(Ts ...);
};


template<typename ... Ts>
struct S {
    template<typename ... Us>
    void lol(FPtr<Us ..., Ts ...>) {}

    template<typename ... Us>
    void foo(void (*)(Ts ..., Us ...)) {}

    template<typename ... Us>
    void bar(void (*)(Us ..., Ts ...)) {}
};


void f(int, float) {}
void g(float, int) {}


int main() {
    S<int> s;

    s.lol<float>(FPtr<float, int>(g));
    s.foo<float>(f);
    s.bar<float>(g);
}
```

The error message is:

```
$ clang++ -std=c++14 t27.cpp -Wall -Wextra -pedantic
t27.cpp:31:4: error: no matching member function for call to 'bar'
        s.bar<float>(g);
        ~~^~~~~~~~~~
t27.cpp:18:7: note: candidate template ignored: failed template argument deduction
        void bar(void (*)(Us ..., Ts ...)) {}
             ^
```

Note: I have reported this bug on the [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66670) and [LLVM](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=23949) bug trackers.

Comment: Maybe g++ 5.1 fix this issue.

Comment: Example may be simplified to [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3cf49423a0d67d49).

Comment: @Jarod42 this behaves differently; it _does_ compile in both compilers when not relying on auto-deduction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tested this code with both Clang and GCC and they both fail to compile the program. I'd say this is a bug in both compilers. A function parameter pack which occurs before the end of the parameter-list is a non-deduced context. After substituting the explicitly specified template argument(s) it should build the function

```c++
template<>
S<int>::bar(void (*)(float, int));
```

which should match the call. Clang and GCC have had problems in areas like this before and their diagnostics are known to have been less than helpful. Surprisingly however [VC++](http://rextester.com/URI74933) compiles the code.

Consider the following which works under both compilers.

```c++
template<class... Ts>
struct S {
    template<class... Us>
    void bar(Us..., Ts...);
};

int main() {
    S<int>().bar<int>(1, 2);
}
```

Your program has the same semantics and should be treated equally.

Comment: How does your code have the same semantics as mine? Yours doesn't pass a function pointer. I have encountered this issue __only__ with function pointers. Technically both our programs are isomorphic to `int main();`, but I'm passing that function pointer for a reason...

Comment: @mic_e I'm giving an example on how your program behaves similarly. No template argument deduction is being performed, so my constructor has the signature `S(int, int)` just like your constructor should have `S(void (*)(float, int))` when the template arguments are substituted.